# am charts labeltext fonsize can't change

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I need to show my percentage value in my bar chart within the cylinder but some of the value is missing.
    So how can I show the missing values in my chart?Attached Screenshot.
    # am trying fontSize also.

[image]

Comment: Post a working fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the chart will not show labels if they can't fit within the chart. In your particular case, you'll want to set [`showAllValueLabels`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#showAllValueLabels) to true in your graph objects:

```
"graphs": [{
  // ...
  "showAllValueLabels": true,
  // ...
}, 
 // repeat for each graph in the array
]
```